# TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, exception, django-templates, django-cms

I am using django-cms app in my django project.
I encountered the following error without any significant changes I made.

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: cms/new.html
```

I checked the presence of django-cms installed in the site-packages dir, also found the 'new.html' file in its right place in the app.
Moreover, I found this line, in the django debug page, which puzzled me much:

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
.......
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/templates/cms/new.html (File exists)
.......
```

according to this line, it is supposed that django has already found the template. So, what is wrong?

Comment: Then it's confusing. Could you paste main part of the debug page?

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy it from the django-cms folder into you projects template directory.

Answer (score 0):

This directory does not seems to be a Django template dir.

In your settings.py file, there is a definition of TEMPLATE_DIR var:

For instance:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    ROOT_PATH = '/template',
)
```

You should put here the right directory, containing your "new.html" template file.

Comment: You mean os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'template') inside TEMPLATE_DIR? Also please check doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/ first.

Answer (score 0):

two ways:
first,make sure you have put your app in the settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'mysite',
    # ...... the rest of installed apps
)
```

second, you can directly set TEMPLATE_DIRS

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/mysite/templates',
)
```